# Node.js: Server.js is getting cluttered with functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I have a `server.js` with many functions.

```
app.post '/record2', (req,res) ->
app.post '/record', (req,res) ->
app.post '/incoming', (req,res) ->
app.post '/call', (req,res) ->

etc..
```

It's starting to become very confusing. What's the best way to make the server.js cleaner and easier to understand?

Thanks

Comment: Functions doesn't make code confusing. Only the code inside them.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're using Express?  Something I've done in the past is create modules for related handlers. E.g.,

Something like this in `record-handlers.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    record2: function(req, res) { ... },
    record: function(req, res) { ... }
};
```

And then in `server.js`:

```
var recordHandlers = require('./record-handlers');

app.post('/record2', recordHandlers.record2);
app.post('/record', recordHandlers.record);
...
```

*My apologies for converting your Coffeescript to JS - I don't know CS at all.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/hueniverse/postmile/blob/master/web/server.js) (lines 231 through 235.)

```
switch (config.method) {

    case 'GET': server.get(config.path, internals.preprocessRequest, routes, config.handler, internals.finalizeResponse); break;
    case 'POST': server.post(config.path, internals.preprocessRequest, routes, config.handler, internals.finalizeResponse); break;
    default: process.exit(1); break;
}
```

the routes and the handlers are in different modules.

Answer (score 0):

Another strategy would be to use a catch-all route like this :

```
/:action
```

and use a switch statement to call the required function based on the value of

`req.param('action')`